# Visual Studio 2010 Express C# limitations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I am trying to develop the nerddinner mvc website, so I downloaded Visual Studio 2010 Express but I do not see an option for MVC or even asp.net website.  Can I download this for Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you download "c# express", or "web developer"?

Comment: That'll be it then... You want web developer

Comment: @Marc - Microsoft now allows for C#, VB.NET and C++ in there Express edition for Windows. Just an FYI :)

Comment: @rock - I'm familiar with the line-up; I guessed, correctly it seems, that someone tagging a question "c#" has *probably* opted for c# express

Comment: yeah you bet. I wasn't correcting, just being a little cheeky, being that you have a diamond beside your name ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual web developer express is what your looking for

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Comment: You may also need to download and install the mvc 3 package if its not included in web developer express

Answer (score 5):

[Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) will let you work on WinForms, Libraries, Etc in C#, VB.NET, and even C++.
[Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) will let you work on ASP.NET **web** applications in both C# and VB.NET

However the Microsoft website calls them both "Visual Studio 2010 Express", they are differentiated by "Windows" and "Web"

**Both are free**